# Why container does not start automatically in Test?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, junit, spring-boot-test

I have the following class

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = OperationCodeRepositoryTest.DockerDatasourceInitializer.class)
public class OperationCodeRepositoryTest {

    @Container
    private static MSSQLServerContainer<?> container = new MSSQLServerContainer<>(
            "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest").acceptLicense()
            .withInitScript("database/init.sql");

    @Autowired
    private OperationCodeRepository repository;

    public static class DockerDatasourceInitializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext, "spring.datasource.url=" + container.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + container.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + container.getPassword());
        }
    }


}

// SOme tests hre
```

Whenever I try to run my tests,I get the following error :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started`

I thought that having the `@Container` would be enough to start the container.
The only option for me is to manually start the container by calling the `start` method in `@BeforeClass`

Ex :

```java
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        try{
            container.start();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

What am I doing wrong ?
THanks